# Find Out Current URL of iFrame

Tags: javascript, url, iframe

Is there anyway of finding out the current URL of an iframe?  If I have an alert message onload set to document.getElementByTagName("iframe")[0].contentWindow.location.href the on safari I receive the current url everytime the iframe page changes.  Unfortunately this doesn't work on Chrome due to Javascript Same Origin Policy guidelines.  Can anyone recommend an alternative approach so someone getting the current URL of the page in an iframe?

Comment: Did u try `document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].src` ?

Comment: I did but unfortunately that only gives you the initial src of the iframe.  For example, if my src="http://en.wikipedia.org" then even if I navigate to another wiki article, that .src only gives me http://en.wikipedia.org instead of changing it.

Comment: You can't access iframe's changed `src` if that belongs to external 3rd party domain.

Answer (score 0):

There could be different approaches to jump over same origin policy:

I would suggest `postMessages`
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.postMessage

should work with Firefox 3.5, Opera 10, Safari 4.0/Chrome 3.0+, Internet Explorer 8.0. And yet, you have to have access to both domains.

you may also try something like old school `XhrIframeProxy` or even somehow, `Xdomain requests` but I am not sure latter has good support yet

Comment: I tried to do postMessage but I believe you have to have control over both domains for it to work.  I have Page A which contains an iframe.  The iframe is always going to be within the en.wikipedia.org domain.  I tried to set the postMessage to go off during onload and have the event listing within my main page but to no avail :(

Comment: yea, that's true, you need access for both to be able put javascript which will call message to parent window

Comment: Is it possible for there to exist a solution that can obtain the current URL?

Comment: do not think so, at least there is no straight way of taking it, SOP is kinda strong rule